# DAX code to count number of orders with n total units

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I've got a list of order lines (first table of the screenshot attached). I'd like to know how many orders have 1 unit, how many 2 units, etc.

I usually do this with 2 pivot tables (as shown in the screenshot attached). The problem is that I have to create an intermediate table and if I have more than 1million orders I couldn't have this approach due to excel's number of rows limit.

I've tried using CALCULATE in several ways, but I can't find the correct way to do it...

Here is the screenshot: [image: Tables]

Thanks in advance!

Jorge

EDIT: I use MS Excel 2017, not Power BI

Comment: Do you use Power Pivot only or do you also use Power BI?

Comment: Excel and Power Pivot (no Power BI)

Comment: I've come up with a solution using the [SUMMARIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx) function but it seems that it's not available in Power Pivot..

Comment: I use DAX Studio, so I guess I could use it. Could you share it, please? :)

Comment: Sure! Or else you can give a shot to Power BI, which is pretty cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is using the function SUMMARIZE (one nested in the other), like this:

```
SUMMARIZE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Orders, 
        Orders[OrderNo],
        "Sum of Units", SUM ( Orders[Units] ) 
    ),
    [Sum of Units],
    "Number of Orders", COUNTROWS (
        SUMMARIZE(
            Orders,
            Orders[OrderNo],
            "Sum of Units", SUM ( Orders[Units] )
        )
    )
)
ORDER BY [Sum of Units] ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution involves using the [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/) function, which seems to be only available in `Power BI, Analysis Services 2016, or Excel 2016`.

`SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` is a much more efficient way to build summary table.

The two summary tables are rebuilt using the expression as follows in Power BI:

[image: new table]

```
Order Summary = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Orders[OrderNo],
    "Sum of Units", SUM(Orders[Units])
)
```

-

```
Unit Summary = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Order Summary'[Sum of Units],
    "Number of Orders", COUNTROWS('Order Summary')
)
```

The result will be as expected:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I hope there would be a solution like that in Excel 2016